# IF THEN Statement in SQL to OpenEdge

Tags: sql, if-statement, openedge

I'm struggeling with an if statement towards an OpenEdge database via ODBC. The query I have works like a charm, but Progress wants me to define the if statement different and I have no clue. Is there anyone who can define the correct query for me?

```
    IF            
    {Crediteur code|type=string} = 'HOEFASTE'
 BEGIN       
    (SELECT
        inok."vest-kd-arvo"+RTRIM('-') + RIGHT(CAST((inok."inok-nr" + 1000000) AS varchar(7)),6) AS inokvalue
        ,RTRIM("leso-kd")+RTRIM('-')+inok."vest-kd-arvo"+RTRIM('-')+CAST("inok-nr"AS varchar(6)) AS inokdisplay
        ,RIGHT(CAST((inok."inok-nr") AS varchar(7)),6) + '-' + inok."vest-kd-arvo" + '-' + RTRIM("leso-kd") AS inoknr
        ,RTRIM("leso-kd") AS soortfact
    FROM
        PUB.inok
    WHERE
        inok."vcdc-nr" = {Administratie|type=int32}
        AND inok."inss-kd" NOT IN ('H','G')
    )
ELSE        
    (SELECT   
        inok."vest-kd-arvo"+RTRIM('-') + RIGHT(CAST((inok."inok-nr" + 1000000) AS varchar(7)),6) AS inokvalue
        ,RTRIM("leso-kd")+RTRIM('-')+inok."vest-kd-arvo"+RTRIM('-')+CAST("inok-nr"AS varchar(6)) AS inokdisplay
        ,RIGHT(CAST((inok."inok-nr") AS varchar(7)),6) + '-' + inok."vest-kd-arvo" + '-' + RTRIM("leso-kd") AS inoknr
        ,RTRIM("leso-kd") AS soortfact
    FROM
        PUB.inok
    WHERE
        inok."rela-kd-kre" = {Crediteur code|type=string}
        AND inok."vcdc-nr" = {Administratie|type=int32}
        AND inok."inss-kd" NOT IN ('H','G')
     )
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, only your `WHERE`-clause is different, based on "Crediteur code".

You could move the IF inside of the `WHERE`-clause. That will leave you with a single `SELECT`-statement. Does this alternative work for you?

```
SELECT   
    inok."vest-kd-arvo"+RTRIM('-') + RIGHT(CAST((inok."inok-nr" + 1000000) AS varchar(7)),6) AS inokvalue
    ,RTRIM("leso-kd")+RTRIM('-')+inok."vest-kd-arvo"+RTRIM('-')+CAST("inok-nr"AS varchar(6)) AS inokdisplay
    ,RIGHT(CAST((inok."inok-nr") AS varchar(7)),6) + '-' + inok."vest-kd-arvo" + '-' + RTRIM("leso-kd") AS inoknr
    ,RTRIM("leso-kd") AS soortfact
FROM
    PUB.inok
WHERE
    inok."rela-kd-kre" = (CASE WHEN {Crediteur code|type=string} = 'HOEFASTE' THEN inok."rela-kd-kre" ELSE {Crediteur code|type=string} END)
    AND inok."vcdc-nr" = {Administratie|type=int32}
    AND inok."inss-kd" NOT IN ('H','G')
```

Comment: As far as can see this was the solution I needed! I'm going to test right now.